# Aliased over existing command

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I was trying to remember how to alias commands when I accidentally thought this was a good idea:

```
alias exit='e'
```

I had overwritten the exit command! While searching for the answer I saw this here: http://www.linfo.org/alias.html
 "unalias removes not only aliases created during the current session but also permanent aliases that are listed in system configuration files." I don't know exactly what this entails but I didn't want to somehow lose the exit command forever.

I couldn't find anything that definitively answered my question, but when I exited out of the terminal and reopened it, I typed exit and it worked and is still working.
Could someone explain what I did and if exiting out of the terminal(by clicking the x) is a true solution to the problem?

Comment: It is not helpful to downvote without explaining how to improve the question.

Comment: @Scott I'm not the downvoter, but I suspect it's because the question is not really a [programming question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) per se and more of a general unix/linux one. It would seem to be a better fit on the [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) sites.

Comment: I looked at SuperUser and this seemed to have the answer of why closing the window fixed the problem. http://superuser.com/questions/888276/stop-exit-from-running/888832#888832

Comment: @hopper I agree that the question might be in the gray area between stackoverflow/askubuntu/superuser/unix.  So I don't necessarily care that the question was downvoted. I just think it doesn't help a new user to fix their question when a downvote has no amplifying comment.